# Extend Fontello icons

Tags: less, icon-fonts, fontello

I'm trying to extend icon pseudoclasses generated by Fontello in less.

Now while this works:

```
.icon-extended:before:extend(.icon-caret-n:before) {}
```

This doesn't:

```
ul.checked li:before:extend(.icon-ok:before) {color: #4fa33b;}
```

Can't see why?

The `li:before` in this case will get the content definition from `.icon-ok:before`, but not the general styles from `[class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before`.

Seems like a bug to me?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, "not implemented" feature at most. `Extend` does not look for any "superset(s)" of the specified selector. For the same reason it won't extend a simple `*` selector (which is a "superset" of the `.icon-ok:before` too). However, taking into account that there's `extend(... all)` option that does implement a sort of "superset matching" (just for different kind of "supersets"), it probably would make sense to at least consider this new extension. I'd recommend you to write a dedicated issue-report/feature-request [here](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues).

Answer (score 2):

**Your first case...**

```
.icon-extended:before:extend(.icon-caret-n:before) {}
```

...you are extending something that has a class itself named `.icon-extended` so that class also matches the selectors `[class^="icon-"]`, `[class*=" icon-"]`, thus why it works (it has nothing to do with the `:extend` in this case).

**Your second case...**

```
ul.checked li:before:extend(.icon-ok:before) {color: #4fa33b;}
```

...you are extending something that does not have the a `icon-` value noted in its selector `ul.checked li`, and so would not and should not match either `[class^="icon-"]`, `[class*=" icon-"]`. Now your extension does not change the class name, but rather just adds the selector to the code block defining `.icon-ok:before` (and only that code block). The LESS extension is looking purely at the selector string `.icon-ok:before` and is not "intelligent" in knowing that such a selector would match the other selector strings `[class^="icon-"]`, `[class*=" icon-"]` (this is essentially what seven-phases-max's comment was about). So you have to do it explicitly, probably best like so:

```
ul.checked li:before:extend(
  .icon-ok:before,
  [class^="icon-"]:before,
  [class*=" icon-"]:before) {
    color: #4fa33b;
}
```

Comment: You example would result in a error (`{}` after `&:extend(...)` is illegal for some reason). One of [those](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7727889#file-20239175-less) will work.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Thanks. The less2css.org site has been down and that is where I normally test all my code, so I had not had an opportunity to test that.

Comment: You can test also with http://winless.org/online-less-compiler (though it provides only recent version of the LESS compiler)